# How to perform Insert when more tables are related

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have Created 3 tables in database as 
tbProducts, tbLineOfAuthority, tbProductLineOfAuthority

tbProducts Contains Following feilds

- ProductId (PK) Identity
- ProductName
- ProductDescription

tbLineOfAuthority Contains Following feilds

- LineOfAuthorityId (PK) Identity
- LineOfAuthorityName

tbProductLineOfAuthority Contains Following feilds

- ProductLineOfAuthorityId (PK)
- ProductId (FK)
- LineOfAuthority (FK)

Now tbLineOfAuthority contains following Data Like

- 1 - Electronic Insurance
- 2 - Credit
- 3 - Casuality
- 4 - Debit

In the frontend I have the form with the following feilds

- Product Name (Textbox)
- Product Description (MultiLine Textbox)
- Line Of Authority (Checkboxes of All Line of Authority)

If user will fill the above form with the following data

- "Mobile Phones" as Product Name
- "We provide good Mobile Phones..." as Product Description
- "Casuality" as Line Of Authority(User will check "Casuality" check box)

Now my Question How to perform Insert Operation in ms sql server based on the above requirement and if more than two tables are related by foreign key.

I have written stored procedure as

```
        Insert into tbProduct(ProductName, ProductDescription)
        Values(@ProductName, @ProductDescription)
```

I am confused how will I write a stored procedure Which will automatically Update tbProductLineOfAuthority (ProductId and LineOfAuthorityId)

Also what will happen when user will select multiple Line of Authority from  check boxes
in the form, I mean If User will select Casuality, Credit and Debit.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you will have to pass 3 parameters for `tbProducts` and `tbLineOfAuthority` table something like below. Once record inserted, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the newly generated `IDENTITY` value [Considering that the PK columns on both this tables are `IDENTITY` column].

```
create procedure sp_insert_ops (@ProductName, 
@ProductDescription,
@tbLineOfAuthority)
as
begin

declare @tbProduct_ID INT;

Insert into tbProduct(ProductName, ProductDescription)
Values(@ProductName, @ProductDescription);

SELECT @tbProduct_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();    

INSERT INTO tbProductLineOfAuthority(ProductId, LineOfAuthority)   
VALUES(@tbProduct_ID, NULL);

end
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... But I don't need to fill the data in tbLineOfAuthority as this table already contains all the data.                                                                                           I don't need the statement                                          Insert into tbLineOfAuthority(LineOfAuthorityName)                                                     Values(@tbLineOfAuthority);                                                                                        in the above stored procedure.... Please help me!!!

Comment: Then how will you get the identity column (LineOfAuthorityId) value for the `tbLineOfAuthority` table? If you don't have that, then you will have to pass `NULL` in insert statement. check edited answer.